# How to connect to SQLite3 database server?

Tags: database, linux, model, sqlite

I understand that SQLite3 does not operate under the client-server database application model, so I was wondering how one would actually connect to a "running" database server with a SQLite3 back.

Meaning if I were to have a database server running on Linux with a SQLite3 back, how would clients connect to this server? Would I have to use another RDBMS?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: I did answer, but googling for `sqlite` would have more quickly given an answer than asking here....

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any database server running SQLlite3. You can just have applications using SQLlite3 (there is no client - server protocol involved). The data is in some files accessed by the `libsqlite3` library linked inside the application. (so the data is local to the system running that application).

So by definition you cannot connect to a SQLlite3 database server. Such thing don't exist.

Read the http://www.sqlite.org/ front-page, which starts with

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

And the wikipage [sqllite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqllite)

If you want to have a database server (with external, possibly *remote*, applications interacting thru a client-server protocol with it) switch to [PostGreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Clients that connect to SQLite "server" just use API that looks like connection. Library for "connection" is embedded into application.