# Is there a way to connect Python to an external sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, vps

I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding whether it's possible to access SQLITE3 (using Python) when the SQLITE database is hosted externally:

I have my SQLITE3 database hosted on my VPS (alongside some other stuff that doesn't really matter) - rather than having it as a local file with my Python program.
Therefore, is it possible for me to connect to the SQLITE database which is hosted on my VPS, or will the SQLITE DB **have** to be hosted locally for me to be able to do this?

The reason I want it to be accessible from my VPS is because I want to be able to run the program on multiple computers and them all have the same access to the database- if this isn't possible, are there any other options which would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to have a database server with external, possibly remote, applications interacting a client-server protocol switch to PostgreSQL, MariaDB, etc.

see: [How to connect to SQLite3 database server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010565/how-to-connect-to-sqlite3-database-server)